# How do you add hexadecimal numbers properly in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, type-conversion, hex

I have two hexadecimal numbers that I am trying to add, but they never add properly when I compare them to what I get on a calculator.

My variables:

> baseaddress = 7FF73EE70000

> addresses = 1DB81B0

My code is:

```
((Hex(Convert.ToInt64(baseaddress, 16)) + Hex(Convert.ToInt64(addresses))))
```

That gives me:

> 7FF73EE700001DB81B0

Which is just the two numbers next to each other.

When those two are added properly, it will be:

> 7FF740C281B0

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Get numbers from input hex strings, then do calculations on numbers, then format result to hex string:

```
Hex(Convert.ToUInt64(baseaddress, 16) + Convert.ToUInt64(addresses, 16))
```

Comment: @LinkZelda please see: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)